# queryset when building django form

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-queryset

I am trying to get specific querysets based when a customer-specific form loads, showing only that customer's name (embedded as an ID field), its respective locations and users.

The idea is to select one user and any number of locations from a multichoice box.

I've tried to pass the ID as a kwarg but am getting a KeyError. I've tried the kwarg.pop('id') as found on the web and same issue. Any advice?

forms.py

```
class LocGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = LocationsGroup
        fields = ('group_name', 'slug', 'customer', 'location', 'user_id',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = kwargs.pop('id')
        super(LocGroupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['customer'].queryset = Customers.objects.get(pk=qs)
        self.fields['location'].queryset = CustomerLocations.objects.filter(customer_id=qs)
        self.fields['user_id'].queryset = CustomerUsers.objects.filter(customer_id=qs)
```

here is my view. it's just a generic view

views.py

```
class LocGroupCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = LocGroupForm
    template_name = 'ohnet/a_gen_form.html'
```

the template is a dry template I use for all my forms- admittedly something I mostly stole from a tutorial

```
{% extends "ohnet/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    {% load static %}
    <div class="container">
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

[image: KeyError 'id']

This is the KeyError from the form load.

Comment: It means you construct a `LocGroupForm`, where you did not pass the `id` parameter...

Comment: but the ID is within the params of the calling page. It's the customer ID.

Comment: can you share the view where you get this error...? [edit] the question.

Comment: I have updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a value for the `id` when constructing the `LocGroupForm`, you can do that by overriding `get_form_kwargs`:

```
class LocGroupCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = LocGroupForm
    template_name = 'ohnet/a_gen_form.html'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['id'] = …
        return kwargs
```

You will need to fill in the `…` that specifies the value passed as `id` to the form. This might for example be `self.request.user.pk`, or a URL parameter with `self.kwargs['name-of-url-parameter']`